# show or hide table using javascript(not with salesforce rerender attribute)

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller, method-invocation

To save processing time I want to call method from javascript instead of controller.

This is my method in controller

```
public void showSupplier() {
        showSup = true;
    }

    public void hideSupplier(){
        showsup = false;
        }
```

Show and hide table without using apex controller and rerender.

I want to show / hide section with javacsript

Previously @SfdcPro using apex:outputpanel for hiding and showing the table.

When user try to mouse over no first table. Second table should display.

when user try to move out mouse from first table. Second table should not be visible to user..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussed with @SfdcPro.

Previously @SfdcPro using **apex:outputpanel** for hiding and showing the table.

When user try to mouse over in first table. Second table should display.

when user try to move out mouse from first  table. Second table should not be visible to user..

SO below is the code for this requirement.

```
<apex:page controller="HidePanelCtrl">
    <apex:form >

          <table width="100%" border="1" onmouseout="showOrHideFunction();" onmouseover="showOrHideFunction();" id="tableId1">
             <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                    First Table
                </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       <table width="100%" style="display:none;"  border="1" id="tableId2">
          <tr>
             <th  style="background-color:#e3e3d7;"> <b>Supplier Description </b></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td >
                Second Table
             </td>
          </tr>
       </table>

        <script>
        var showOrHide = true; 
        function showOrHideFunction(){
           if(showOrHide){
               document.getElementById('tableId2').style.display = '';
               showOrHide = false;
               }
           else{
               document.getElementById('tableId2').style.display = 'none';
               showOrHide = true;
           }
        }
        </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is this answer relevant to the question?

Comment: Actually I discussed with @SfdcPro in chat about requirement.

Comment: Please also add those thigns to the question and/or answer. The intent is that both question and answer become a catalogued solution in public  service. That only works if the question is focused on a specific issue and the answer relates to that (and when the title describes the issue).  It's preferable that all code in an answer is explained, so that it is clear why it solves the issue.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Thanks for pointing out. I have added the details in Ans and qus.